# About weight of $M\in\mathcal{O}_{\chi_\lambda}$ in the Category $\mathcal{O}$

Tags: lie-algebras, weyl-group, weights

Given $M\in\mathcal{O}_{\chi_\lambda}$, how does the weights of $M$ relate to $\lambda$? Is it something about $W\cdot\lambda$?

Comment: Well yes, all composition factors will be of the form $L(w\cdot \lambda)$ and all weights of these are $\leq w\cdot \lambda$.

Comment: Does it mean $M\in\mathcal{O}_{\chi_\lambda}$ has highest weight in the form $w\cdot\lambda$?

Comment: Yes (I am fairly sure this should be somewhere in Humphreys' Category $\mathcal{O}$ book).

Comment: I have searched the key word "highest" in Humphreys' Category $\mathcal{O}$ book, but fail to find statement saying weight of $M\le w\cdot\lambda$ and $M$ has highest weight in the form $w\cdot\lambda$. Can you elaborate more or even give a proof here please?

Comment: Suppose $M=M^{[\mu_1]}\oplus M^{[\mu_2]}$, where $M^{[\mu]}=\bigoplus_{\nu\in [\mu]} M_{\nu}$. It can be shown $M^{[\mu_i]}$ is $U(\mathfrak{g})$-submodule of $M$ (exercise 1.1 in  Humphreys' Category $\mathcal{O}$ book). Now $M\in\mathcal{O}_{\chi_\lambda}\implies M^{[\mu_i]}\in \mathcal{O}_{\chi_\lambda}$. By your claim, there are $w_i\in W$ such that $w_i\cdot\lambda$ is the highest weight of $M^{[\mu_i]}$. Then $M^{[\mu_i]}=M^{[w_i\cdot\lambda]}$. Thus $M=M^{[w_1\cdot\lambda]}\oplus M^{[w_2\cdot\lambda]}$. In case $\lambda$ is not integral, what is the highest weight of $M$?

Comment: The module $M$ doesn't need to be highest weight module.

Comment: I does NOT assume M is highest weight module. But my professor and you have said that any $M\in\mathcal{O}_{\chi_\lambda}$ has highest weight in the form $w\cdot\lambda$. I feel confused about that.

Comment: You need to be a bit more precise. All the highest weights of the composition factors of $M$ will be like that.

Comment: Now let me summarize what I understand:1. We DO know all composition factors of $M$ is isomorphic to $L(w\cdot \lambda)$ with highest weight $w\cdot\lambda$ for some $w\in W$. 2. In general $M$ is not a highest weight module, and hence we DO NOT know what the weights of $M$ itself look like. Am I right or wrong?